# How can I get replacement stickers for a new lego set?

Tags: stickers, moc

I recently bought a Lego Fire Boat (set number 60005) but for some reason, when I opened the box and shook out the contents (as I normally do) no sticker sheet fell out. I was wondering if you could help me out here, as this set is the jewel of my crown. I need them to create a (rather unusual) fire rescue MOC and film but I cannot do this without the stickers. If you can help me here, it'd be much appreciated. Thanks guys!

Ciaran

P.S. can you give me somesolutions?

Comment: Although this question is specifically about new sets, the answers in the question flagged as duplicate are valid even if that one is about an older set. Besides, the solution goes for any product you buy: not satisfied? Go to your reseller and explain the problem. Failing that, contact the producer. The LEGO customer service is very friendly and their number is on the box you bought.

Answer (score 4):

LEGO Customer Service will be probably be happy to help you out. They've been happy to replace missing or broken parts for me in the past. They have an online service for requesting replacement parts here:

https://wwwsecure.lego.com/en-us/service/replacementparts

I don't think sticker sheets are listed in the inventories on that page though, so you'll have to add it manually using the "I can't find what I'm looking for" link at the bottom. Once the sheet is added to your cart, you just need to checkout and provide an address for shipping purposes.

If you have any problems, you can also contact customer service directly from this page:

https://wwwsecure.lego.com/service/contactus/

Comment: Link rotted away, this seems to be the new one for replacement parts:  https://wwwsecure.us.lego.com/en-us/service/contactus